# WSO2 API Manager redirecting to wrong address

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm publishing one of our APIs on WSO2 API Manager. The API has the following resource that I access through a HTTP GET call: http://content.my-company.com/data/articles/123456, where "123456" is the article id.

On the API Manager, I'm registering the version v1 of this API, under the "contents" context, so that I'm able to access it through: http://api.my-company.com/contents/v1/data/articles/123456

The problem is that I'm currently getting a 404 error, and looking at the API log, it shows that the request the API is receiving from WSO2 is: http://content.my-company.com/http%3A//content.my-company.com/data/articles/123456, instead of http://content.my-company.com/data/articles/123456

Anyone has an idea on why the request is being redirected incorrectly to my API?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,

Alex.

Comment: Hi, May I know answers to below questions,to get a better idea on your problem.                         1)when creating the API,what is the entered endpoint of the API and the API Resource Url-pattern for that API?      2)After publish the API,what is the http/https url displays in the APIStore view of your API?                2)Can you copy and paste your trying REST request?                                       Thanks;

Comment: Hi, lalaji! 

1)when creating the API,what is the entered endpoint of the API and the API Resource Url-pattern for that API? 
The endpoint is something like:  http://127.0.0.1:8280/content/1.0.0/articles/123456
and
the url-pattern is: (prefix) /content/1.0.0 (url pattern) /articles/* 

2)After publish the API,what is the http/https url displays in the APIStore view of your API? 
http://127.0.0.1:8280/content/1.0.0

3)Can you copy and paste your trying REST request? 
GET http://127.0.0.1/content/1.0.0/articles/123456

Thanks a lot,
Alex

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the late reply. I could see the below isssues in your defined API. 1) You have to remove the '/articles/123456' part from the endpoint url,as you have defined it as a url-pattern in API resources section seperatly..2) You have to enter the real back-end API/service endpoint as the endpoint URL in add-API page of publisher app[In your given URL,the endpoint URL is same as the URL which is generated for a published API in WSO2 API Manager,which is shown in APIStore view],to get the responses correclty from backend..Thanks;